# How to select files inseveral inputs at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have a problem with multiple file inputs.

For example I have two file inputs like this.

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="iamge_files">
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file">
```

And I have a button For adding images. Something like this

```
<button id="choose-files">Add files to upload</button>
```

How can I select files for both inputs at the same time. Just with one click onthe button.

Comment: Why do you need to 2 file input?

Comment: I am sure you can't open 2 'browse file' windows at the same time. Suggest you to make a multiple file select

Comment: They are being handled for different purposes, so I need this....

Comment: They are already multiple. They need to be passed same files just with one browse window.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?